# Levels of a categorical variable in Wilkinson-Rogers notation without intercept

Tags: regression, mixed-model, notation

I would like some clarification regarding a regression specified using [Wilkinson-Rogers](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346786) notation to produce coefficients for all levels in a categorical variable.

Consider the regression specifed by `Income ~ Sex`, where `Sex` is a categorical variable with two levels, `Male` and `Female`. This regression will produce two coefficients, one for the intercept, and one for either the level `Male` or `Female`, as the effect of one level of `Sex` is automatically incorporated into the intercept.

My question is what coefficients should the notation `Income ~ Sex - 1` produce? This is used to exclude the intercept term. In `R`, which uses a 'modified form' of Wilkinson-Rogers this fits coefficients to both levels of `Sex`. However, in `Matlab`, one level is still dropped, thus only one coefficient is produced.

Comment: I guess in some way it has to do with how you code the dummy variables: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/115052/22199. It is not clear to me whether you should always use $k$ dummies for $k$ levels if there is no intercept, or whether it is acceptable to always use $k-1$.

Comment: (I added the tag `mixed-model` because I think this relates very often with mixed models too. I think it will get your answer better visibility in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unsatisfying answer is that there is no definite reference on what to do in that case.

R actually tries to be somewhat smart and allow only the *first* dummy value to be fully encoded. Any additional nominal variables will still be "truncated". Even more annoyingly though is not definite way to control which value is fully represented in $k$ levels instead of $k-1$. Unofficially changing the order for which you write your model (ie `y ~ -1 + x1 + x2` or `y ~ -1 + x2 + x1`) does that within `lm` but you are still in the whim of a developer's interpretation of W-R notation for other functions. MATLAB apparently said: "*Forget it, if you want full variables just encode them yourself using `dummyVar`*" and stopped bothering on the issue.

Comment: thanks, this is a helpful insight into the workings of matlab's regression functionality. So, I am guessing from your answer that the W-R paper doesn't really specify what `Y ~ X - 1` means if `X` is a categorical variable... I had a read but couldn't see anything.

Comment: Not it does not. Further more it does not go ahead and define the difference between `y ~ -1  + x` and `y ~ 0 + x` which is a bit of a bummer... In fairness this was supposed to be used in a particular package GENSTAT and maybe it was fine for that purpose. It was not designed with the idea of a universal statistical modelling language. I do not have access to the paper at the moment but I think of the top of my head that the use of `I()` not defined either and this why MATLAB did not support.

Comment: @TomLane might want to weight in on this too.