# Do you have to pre-process ordinal variables for regression neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

As neural networks are a set of linear operators, using categorical variables with an arbitrary assignment of order where there is no justification (e.g., Doctor:1, Teacher:2) will teach the model to treat higher values as more important.

However is this true if you add a non-linear activation function between layers--this will transform the network to be non-linear and as such there would be no need to remove the ordered nature of nominal variables using, for example, non-hot encoder.

Comment: Do you know about the [standard way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/593450/247274) to encode categories? // I do not see doctor/teacher as having any order to it.

Comment: @Dave but the ordering of categorical features that do not have any inherent order (such as above) should not matter with non-linear models such as random forests as the predictions are evaluated based on if-statements rather than coefficients. My question, therefore, is if you transform a linear neural network to be non-linear by adding non-linear activation functions such as ReLU, then should I still worry about the handling of categorical features?

Comment: What order to the categorical features is there?